# Send current geo position on time interval

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to send my current location, but not always, only for every 10 minutes. And also to avoid high battery costs.

Is it available to set timer for this action?

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onMyLocationChange(Location loc) {
            sendPosition(loc.getLat(), loc.getLong())
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update a datetime variable each time sendPosition is called. And in the location change event check if the difference between current datetime and the datetime variable is more than 10 minutes before calling sendPosition again.